# can the font type of an Edittext,Radio Button and CheckBox be changed in Android

Tags: android, checkbox, radio-button, android-edittext

I am a beginner in android.I can able to change the font type of a Textview in Android.But I have to use .ttf file in asset folder,to bring this kind of font change.

```
TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.text);
text.setText(msg);
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/handsean.ttf");
text.setTypeface(font);
```

The above code is what I used to change the font of a text View.but I need to change the font type of the text of Radio Button,Edittext and Check box(which Im also used in my application) as well.Plz help me out here.Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess, you have to use the same code for the other views too. Have you tried using the code to EditText etc.??

Comment: Yes you have to use the same code for edittext too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you have to follow the same code wht u have mentioned here.This will work for other controls too like Edittext,CheckBox etc.

Comment: what about without assets folder? (with font folder that in new in android)

Answer (score 7):

The selected answer was missing the code, so here it is:

**EditText**

```
EditText editText = (EditText) layout.findViewById(R.id.edittext);
editText.setText(msg);
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/myfont.ttf");
editText.setTypeface(font);
```

**RadioButton**

```
RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) layout.findViewById(R.id.radiobutton);
radioButton.setText(msg);
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "fonts/myfont.ttf");
radioButton.setTypeface(font);
```

**CheckBox**

```
CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) layout.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
checkBox.setText(msg);
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/myfont.ttf");
checkBox.setTypeface(font);
```

## Multiple Views

If you need to do this for multiple views across your application, then it may be easier to make a subclass of your `EditText`, `RadioButton`, or `CheckBox`. This subclass sets the font. Below is an example for `CheckBox`.

```
public class MyCheckBox extends CheckBox {

    // Constructors
    public MyCheckBox(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }
    public MyCheckBox(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }
    public MyCheckBox(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    // This class requires myfont.ttf to be in the assets/fonts folder
    private void init() {
        Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(),
                "fonts/myfont.ttf");
        setTypeface(tf);
    }
}
```

It can be used in xml as follows:

```
<com.example.projectname.MyCheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkbox"
    android:text="@string/msg"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:checked="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes the same approach will work for buttons and radio buttons too.
Also you can do this in simple steps as follows

```
Button moreBtn = (Button) events.findViewById(R.id.promotion_event_more_btn);
FontUtils.setTypeface(this, moreBtn, Constants.C_FONT);</code><br>Where "Constants.C_FONT" is set to the path of the font file present in the assets folder.
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it so in .xml file as well

you can use proertiees to do so

```
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="any color"
    android:textAppearance="any appearencde"
```

you can use these with buttons , checboxes etc.

u can do the by code also

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your support library is >=26.0 or using AndroidX in your project. Then add this line to your view in XML

```
      app:fontFamily="@font/myFontFamily"
```

e.g:

```
  <RadioButton
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:id="@+id/language_english"
      android:text="@string/english"
      app:fontFamily="@font/myFontFamily"
      />
```

If you want to use your custom font, read the official document:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml