# Adding custom fonts for android api 14

Tags: android, font-family

**Error**
error: style attribute 'app:attr/fontFamily' not found.
Message{kind=ERROR, text=error: style attribute 'app:attr/fontFamily' not found.

```
<style name="RadioButtonCustomStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.CompoundButton.RadioButton">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimaryDisableOnly">#f44336</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#607ba3</item>
    <item name="app:fontFamily">@font/raleway_medium</item>
</style>
```

I have added raleway_medium.ttf in the **app/assets/font/raleway_medium.ttf**

Comment: You need to set font programmatically like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17113646/6454463) answer

Comment: Thank you @RutvikBhatt, but in this process it makes me to repeat the process many times

Comment: make a method like `public static void setTypeface(RadioButton radioButton){//your code to set typeface}` in Utils class and call it from anywhere like `Utils.setTypeface(objRadio);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by puting your font at the assets folder and using the code below:

`Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "your_font.ttf");
yourTextView.setTypeface(tf);`

Comment: But its difficult for me to repeat the .setTypeFace for multiple views

Comment: Unfortunately this is the only way I know :(

Answer (score 0):

There's a library called Calligraphy. It's used in cases like yours - to replace fonts in all views on older phones. If I'm correct, it doesn't support font resources, but just plain .ttf files. See: https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy

I'm working on a library with support for font resources for older phones. It's working cleaner than Calligraphy, but the library itself is very large, so it may not be best suited for you. The font support commit is well extracted and you can find it here: https://github.com/ZieIony/Carbon/commit/baefcfb1941ecc1b4e293f31f5220ab7abaf4584

And the essential part of the answer is the following method. I guess it was taken from Material Components sources. You can add it to your text fields and buttons to use it to handle the xml attribute.

```
private void handleFontAttribute(TypedArray appearance, int textStyle, int attributeId) {
    WeakReference<android.widget.TextView> textViewWeak = new WeakReference<>(this);
    AtomicBoolean asyncFontPending = new AtomicBoolean();
    ResourcesCompat.FontCallback replyCallback = new ResourcesCompat.FontCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onFontRetrieved(@NonNull Typeface typeface) {
            if (asyncFontPending.get()) {
                android.widget.TextView textView = textViewWeak.get();
                if (textView != null)
                    textView.setTypeface(typeface, textStyle);
            }
        }
         @Override
        public void onFontRetrievalFailed(int reason) {
        }
    };
    try {
        int resourceId = appearance.getResourceId(attributeId, 0);
        TypedValue mTypedValue = new TypedValue();
        Typeface typeface = ResourcesCompat.getFont(getContext(), resourceId, mTypedValue, textStyle, replyCallback);
        if (typeface != null) {
            asyncFontPending.set(true);
            setTypeface(typeface, textStyle);
        }
    } catch (UnsupportedOperationException | Resources.NotFoundException ignored) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Add your font in your folder font (app/res/font).

After that you can use a textview and set the font

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ID"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fontFamily="@font/YourFont"
    android:text="@string/YourText"
    android:textColor="@color/YourColor"
    android:textSize="20dp" />
```

In your style you can try to change "app:fontFamily" with "android:fontFamily"

Hope this will help

Comment: My solution works guys, why do you put me -1 without explication xD ?

Comment: I didn't check that, but Android Developers page says that your solution doesn't work on API 14 - maybe that's the reason